# Linq to SQL using StoredProcedure - How to return a value (insert, update, delete)

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

How do we return a value from a stored procedure

here is my sp looks like:

```
create proc dbo.spInsertGroup
@ID uniqueidentifier
@GroupName varchar(100),
@IsActive bit
AS
BEGIN



insert into tblGroup
values(@ID, @GroupName, @IsActive)

Select @@IDENTITY AS ID

END
```

based on the return value i want to show the user some kind of feedback wether the save was successfull or failed.

```
public void AddInquiry(Inquiry inq)
{
   using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
   {
      using (MyDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
      {
         var results =  dc.spInquiry_Insert(......).ToList();

         transaction.Complete();

         var returnValue = (int)results.ReturnValue; 
         // note that ReturnValue is of type object and must be cast. 
      }
   }
}
```

error:

> Error 39  'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'ReturnValue' and no extension method
>   'ReturnValue' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
using (MyDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
{
    var returnValue = (int)dc.spInsertGroup(.......).ReturnValue;
}
```

You are getting that error because you are calling the .ToList() so the var results is of type List<> that has no ReturnValue property.

If you can't see the ReturnValue property, maybe you need to update the method generated by LINQ

Comment: what is the return type of the spInsertGroup method?
edit: should be something like ISingleResult<spInsertGroupResult>

Answer (score 0):

For a scalar value like the ID, I believe you just say "RETURN @ID"

For a rowset, I believe you select it, similar to your example, and Linq2Sql imports it as a `IEnumerable<>`.

Update:

Since you used `SELECT`, L2S created a `List<T>`. Since the value in the select was an integer, it was a `List<int>`, with only one element.  To retrieve that, it's just `results[0]`.

Or you could change the stored procedure to `return @ID`, and use:

```
var id =  dc.spInquiry_Insert(......);
```

Comment: i have a RETURN @ID in my sp, just updated but still throwing me an error which i posted above

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return any but an INT from a stored proc, however, you're trying to send out a **GUID** - that won't work. You need to rewrite your stored proc to something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spInsertGroup
    @GroupName varchar(100),
    @IsActive bit,
    @ID uniqueidentifier OUTPUT
AS .......
```

Then it's good enough to simply have the `SET @ID = NEWID()` in your stored proc - that works just fine.

Your C# code would now look something like:

```
using(YourDataContext ctx = new YourDataContext())
{
    Guid? newID = new Guid();
    bool? active = true;

    int retVal = ctx.spInsertGroup2("test", active, ref newID);
}
```

and `newID` will contain the new ID after the call.

Comment: i am not getting ToList() may be because in my SP i am returning Return @ID ?

Comment: i update my sp and its returning.. Select @@IDENTITY AS ID 
should i still be using what you have showed above?

Comment: If you have an IDENTITY field (which you happened to **not** mention in your post), you can retrieve that, yes - but I would recommend you use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead of @@IDENTITY - see here: http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/01/17/2736.aspx and a great many other posts (and questions here on SO) as to why.