# How to do this SQL in LINQ?

Tags: asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I would like to know how i could do the following using LINQ (C#). All help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
DECLARE @productId int

INSERT INTO product(title, studioId, developerId, publisherId, releasedateUK, releasedateUS, certUK, certUS, dateAdded, pageSlug)
VALUES (@title, @studioId, @developerId, @publisherId, CONVERT(Date, @releaseDateUK, 103), CONVERT(Date, @releaseDateUS, 103), @certUK, @certUS, GETDATE(), @Slug)
SET @productId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()   

--Insert Product Details

INSERT INTO productDetails(productId, is3D, is4K, isTriplePlay, hasDVD, hasDigital, running, regiona, regionb, regionc, releaseYear, synopsis, imdbrating)
VALUES (@productId, @is3D, @is4K, @isTriplePlay, @hasDVD, @hasDigital, @runningTime, @regiona, @regionb, @regionc, @releaseYear, @synopsis, @imdbrating)
```

UPDATE: This is from a SPROC i have written, i basically need to insert a product, get that ID so i can then insert on other tables too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this... assuming Product and ProductDetails is a one to many.

If it was a one to one, then you might just set product.ProductDetail = new ProductDetail{};

```
var ctx = new DataBaseContext();

    var product =  new Product{
        Title  = "Title",
        etc..
        etc...
    };



    product.ProductDetails.Add(new ProductDetail{
        is4K = true,
        etc..
        etc..
    });
    ctx.Products.InsertOnSubmit(product);
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: So this would pass the id from the inserted product to the product detail table and so on?

Comment: It should... Assuming id is auto generated .

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a DataContext which will represent your database as Linq Objects.

See here: [How to: Add LINQ to SQL Classes to a Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384470.aspx)
 or here: [Walkthrough: Creating LINQ to SQL Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb384428.aspx)

In the DataContext you will find an entity for each table you have in your database.
When you now want to create a new row in your database you first need to create a new
instance from your entity.

```
Product newProduct = new Product( );
newProduct.Title = "Your own title";
newProduct.StudioId = 1234;
[...]
```

When you are ready in filling your entity with your data, you pass it in your dataContext.

```
YourDataContext.Products.InsertOnSubmit( newProduct );
```

finally you submit your changes:

```
YourDataContext.SubmitChanges( );
```

I recommend a little reading: [Using Linq to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) and [101 LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

(maybe it's a little bit outdated because its from 2007 but you get the idea)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already know some LINQ, however the above is part of a SPROC which saves data to different Tables in my DB. 

Basically i need to insert get that id so i can then insert into the other tables too.

Comment: @thatuxguy Normally you can perform multiple `SubmitChanges` and the `ID` would be present on the `Product` instance. If you use a SPROC you need to return the newly generated id. Maybe this helps [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312416/linq-to-sql-using-storedprocedure-how-to-return-a-value-insert-update-delet)